# Keeping no business logic in the UI layer of an Asp.net MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-standards

I have an MVC 4 project where the UI is strongly typed to a ViewModel. The view has certain elements that need to be shown in certain scenarios. These scenarios are governed by business logic so I don’t want to have some conditional statement like this in the UI

```
If (Role.Equals(“Admin”))
{
  <a href=””> Admin Link here</a>
}
```

What I have is the business layer create a view model for me. So the above statement is now in the business layer as below

```
If (Role.Equals(“Admin”))
{
 ViewModelClassObject.ShowAdminLinks = true;
}
```

And in my UI .aspx layer as below

```
If (model.ShowAdminLinks)
{
  <a href=””> Admin Link here</a>
}
```

Now the problem is this, I have the viewmodel classes in a separate class library which is referenced by both the business and web UI layer. Since the viewmodel class also has properties which map to the UI layer’s textboxes where I perform some validations like, the required field validator, Compare, Range validator, I now need to make a reference to the System.web.mvc layer in my ViewModel class library. Is this bad coding practice? Although the code compiles and builds I get the feeling that I am probably doing something that could possibly be a code smell. Alternatively, I am also considering moving the ViewModel classes back into the Web UI layer and using some sort of a viewmodel builder in the web project to create the view model by calling the business layers methods. This way there will be no need to have a separate ViewModel class library that references the System.Web.MVC dll and my controller can just call this View model builder class to build the view model

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate ViewModels used by web project and DTO's used by business layer.

The reason is that probably you don't need property `ShowAdminLinks` or some dropdown values in business layer. So business layer knows only about the data it needs to know.

This way you get yourself clean multi-tier application. Of course it means you got to do a bit more coding with creating and setting DTOs values. Some use [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for that, but i prefer not to. Why? It's not too hard to do it manually and better yet - no magic.

Comment: Thanks Max. Now going forward I am thinking of keeping the viewmodel in the web UI layer and the business logic that builds the view also in the same web UI layer. The question here is, now part of my business logic is leaking into the view, isn't it?.. although it is only that part which is concerned with the view and if I want to test the logic responsible for creating the view I can do it now without worrying about calling the controller action methods in my test project..

Comment: I wouldn't call it a business logic leak. As i see, controller IS for retrieving data from client (also validating it) and constructing viewmodel. When it comes to fetching data from other resources than request or doing anyting else, it should be moved to another layer - data, service or whatever.

Comment: Your ViewModel could inherit from your business DTO and just add the View specific fields (eg: ShowAdminLinks). Then you'd have a bit more of a separation, while reducing the field mapping burden.

Comment: @AndrewLewis Yep that's also useful sometimes. Also what i have practiced is implicit operator.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have DTO classes created that are a one to one mapping to the database tables. Sometimes I need a List<DTO> in my Viewmodel to display a grid full of records from that table. So I am not sure if inheritance would work for me here. however you do bring up an interesting point that I could perhaps use elsewhere. But then, that again means that I have some viewmodels that inherit from DTO and some that contain them as properties. That is again not very clean me thinks...

Comment: That's why i separate DTO's and domain also. In smaller projects it does not seem reasonable, but when going to large scale it pays off. Reason why i separate DTO's and domain is because sometimes i want to return data from service layer that is combined from multiple domain objects.